# Using python and lxml to get html sources code from web site

Tags: python, xml-parsing, html-parsing, lxml

I am a beginner of python and trying to create a procedure with Python 2.7 which retrieves the betting odds from the following web sites.

**English Version web site:** http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=24-09-2015&venue=hv&raceno=1&lang=en

**Chinese Version web site:** bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=24-09-2015&venue=hv&raceno=1

The data that i want to retrieve is marked in the following image file
https://na.cx/i/Bz873x.jpg

The procedure works well in other web site (e.g. reddit or lxml.de/parsing.html).
But I don't know why the procedure retrieved a different html code that I've retrieved by using Chrome.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from lxml import etree

# print out the sources code of the web site
# work properly on other web sites (e.g. reddit.com or lxml.de/parsing.html)
# but having problem on the betting web site
url = 'http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=24-09-2015&venue=hv&raceno=1'
tree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))

# printing the first horse name in chinese version web site (Doesn't work)
horse_name = tree.xpath('//*[@id="detailWPTable"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a/span/text()')
print horse
```

After running the above procedure, I found that the html code retrieved by Python is different from the html code that I retrieved by using Chrome Function - [View Sources] or [Open Developer Tools].

My question is

1. How can I get the correct html code (Same code as Chrome - View Sources) by using python?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your user-agent is set differently and because some scripts on the page are not executed. You can set the first element in the HTTP request headers, but most importantly you need to render the web page using a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser).

A good example of such a framework working in Python is [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium).